# Uniqueness of idempotent in Brauer's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Brauer's lemma states, that, given a ring $R$ and a minimal left ideal $I$ with $I^2 \neq 0$, there exists an idempotent $e \in R$ with $I = Re$ and $D = eRe$ is a division ring.

My question is, whether $e$ is a unique idempotent. If it is, how can I show this, if it is not, can you give a counter example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $e$ is typically not unique.  For instance, if $V$ is a vector space over some field and $W\subset V$ is a subspace of codimension 1, then the set $I\subseteq\operatorname{End}(V)$ of endomorphisms that vanish on $W$ is a minimal left ideal with $I^2\neq 0$.  The idempotent $e$ can then be any projection whose kernel is $W$ (there is one such projection for every linear complement to $W$ in $V$).

Comment: You are right. I was thinking for at first about the algebra of $2\times 2$ matrices with being the projector onto a one-dimensional subspace. But I made a mistake that led me to conjecture that it must be unique. Thanks for your example.